# $\left (a+b\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}+\left (c+d\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}=7+5\sqrt 2$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, binomial-theorem

Prove that there exist no rational numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that 
$\left (a+b\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}+\left (c+d\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}=7+5\sqrt 2$

My solutions out line

$\left (a+b\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}+\left (c+d\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}=7+5\sqrt 2$

$\implies\left (a-b\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}+\left (c-d\sqrt 2 \right )^{100}=7-5\sqrt 2$

Which is a contradiction as LHS is positive and RHS is negative.

I hope this will satisfy all of you. I wanted to know any other idea to solve this problem

Comment: Can you please give some context for your question?

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I wonder.

Comment: People who down voted this most considered themselves Genius

Comment: I think the downvotes are there because of the OP has just asked a question without context and without showing own work.